# CCSprite with image from URL in cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to get Facebook profile image, but I'm not able to transform the data that I get from facebook into a Texture,

```
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 NSLog(@"sprite nao existe");
 //convert UIImage to CCSprite
 **CCTexture *texture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:image];**


 CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
 sprite.position = ccp(winWidth*.5, winHeight*.5)
```

In the line CCTexture *text... I'm getting this warning, which make the simulator stops/crashes:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage' to parameter of type NSString
```

This is the message when the simulator stops in the Log

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'TextureCache: fileimage MUST not be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: The question & answer you wrote are so good to know. So, I translated them to share with Korean developers. If you mind it, please let me know and it will be deleted at [ctrlaltdel](http://ctrlaltdel.co.kr)

Comment: @KeithPark thanks! I don't mind you translate the question, just make some reference to this source please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CCTexture *texture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:image];
```

Here image must be a NSString not a UIImage. [The reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCTexture.html) will tell you that.

Instead use this method:

```
- (id)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage contentScale:(CGFloat)contentScale
```

Like so:

```
CCTexture *texture = [[CCTexture alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage 
                                           contentScale:image.scale];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this message: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid texture for sprite'

Comment: And you are sure this time that the data retrieved and the image created is a valid image and not a nil object? You may want to try Xcode "QuickLook" at the UIImage to find out (select the image variable in debugger and click the 'eye' icon): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/CustomClassDisplay_in_QuickLook/CH01-quick_look_for_custom_objects/CH01-quick_look_for_custom_objects.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code to set image in your Sprite**

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image.CGImage key:@"BB"];
sprite.position = ccp(winWidth*.5, winHeight*.5)
[self addChild:sprite];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes @LearnCocos2D, you are absolutely right. I have created a category on CCSprite and created a method named

```
+ (id)spriteWithURL:(NSString*)imageURL defaultSprite:(NSString*)defaultImage;
```

. It simply creates a CCSprite from the `defaultImage` and if download of image with the `imageURL` completes, it automatically sets the texture of CCSprite from the downloaded image. You can find out the whole project from [GitHub](https://github.com/sauvikatinnofied/CCSpriteFromURL). Hope this will help you.